# Code isn't working in visual studios no idea why. If anyone could help check it and make suggestions that would be much appreciated

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2019

I'm a student who's only just started coding and I've got a project due soon. I tried adding script to my project and absolutely nothings worked. So, I tried stripping it down and making a button which changes the background colour, even that failed to work. Idk if it's visual studios being bugged out or my code itself. I'll post the code and what the debugger thing says. Any help would be cool.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chinese Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b> Chinese Numbers </b></p>
    <input id="btnPlay" type="button" value="Play" onclick="btnPlay_OnClick" >
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function btnPlay_OnClick() {
        document.bgColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```

'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'.

The program '[16476] iexplore.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[15132] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Details, we need details.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is outside of the `<html>` and `<body>` tag. This means that the script will not be executed in the context of the document.

Instead move your script inside the `<body>` tag, preferably before the closing `</body>` tag.

Also `document` itself has no styles, as it refers to the context of the current document but is not an element by itself.

The `document` object does have a `body` property which refers to the `<body>` element in your document.

To change the background color of the body you need to access the `style` property of the `body` property and set the `backgroundColor` property to a certain color.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chinese Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b> Chinese Numbers </b></p>
    <input id="btnPlay" type="button" value="Play" onclick="btnPlay_OnClick" >
    <script>
        function btnPlay_OnClick() {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for replying. I can't believe I forgot that everything has to be within the html tags. However, I just ran your code and the background didn't change. The debugger says "Proper 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: Whoops, forgot to put `style` inbetween `body` and `backgroundColor`. It should work.